# How to access my layout from onNewToken() of FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: java, android

First of all, I am a great newbie in aAndroid development (and with a English not really perfect).

What is the simplest way to access my layout (simple TextView, here named "text") from onNewToken() method from FirebaseMessagingService class ?
I saw that we regularly talked about BroadcastReceivers but I also read that it was deprecated.
Of course I have errors with findViewById().

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String device_token) {
        @SuppressLint("HardwareIds") String device_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        DeviceService service = DeviceService.retrofit.create(DeviceService.class);
        Call<String> call = service.insertToken(device_token,device_id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    text.setText("Token registered");
                }   else {
                    text.setText("Token registering error");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                text.setText("Token not transmitted");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) is not deprecated, but [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager) is deprecated.

you can register receiver without `LocalBroadcastManager`, using `Context.registerReceiver()`.

And put your response result into [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences), and use the value of `SharedPreferences` as [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) or [Flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/) in your `Activity`, `Fragment` or `ViewModel`.

Or, use event bus with [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) or [Flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/) whatever